# Identifying row pairs in Excel for Mac

Tags: macos, excel, duplicates

I have been given two spreadsheets of names and emails that have been combined. Some of the rows are unique to Spreadsheet1, some of the rows are unique to Spreadsheet2, and some rows are in both spreadsheets.

I have have identified the rows that are in both spreadsheets using the =A2=A1 formula (sorted by email addresses). Each set of dupes can be identified by FALSE in row1 and TRUE in row2. The FALSE/TRUE pairing only exists in the dupes.

I want to delete BOTH rows, not just the duplicate row.

Is there some IF...AND formula I can use that can find a FALSE row that is followed by a TRUE row, and either color-format them both or delete them?

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks for any insight you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(OR(IF(AND(A2=TRUE,A1=FALSE),"Y","")="Y",IF(AND(A2=FALSE,A3=TRUE),"Y","")="Y"),"Y","N")
```

Give that one a try - For your duplicates it will show "Y", for all others it will show "N".
It will show "Y" for both the first line, and the last line of your sheet, so disregard these.

Once you have pasted the formula in, make sure you copy the whole column and `Paste Special > Values` so that you can either conditional format, or filter and delete easily.

Unfortunately it's not the cleanest-looking formula around, but it's functional!